# Setting background panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

I have a panel control over picture box control. Now I want to set the background of the panel as the image is.

[image]

Comment: Good to know that you want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we set `panel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` panel becomes transparent and shows parent background color or image. But `PictureBox` is not container you only place panel on picture box so even if you try `panel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` you will not see image of `PictureBox`. You will try something like this.

```
panel.Parent = pictureBox;
panel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

But take care top and left of `panel` because when you set `pictureBox` as parent. you will also need to set top and left of `panel`.